# Would butterflies prefer drinking blood over nectar?

Tags: zoology, entomology

Knowing that butterflies will drink carrion blood and nectar, I wonder if they would prefer one over the other? The blood has more nutrients like iron and copper that the nectar would not have. Or do they not need nutrients outside of what is found in nectar?

Answer (score 1):

Well nectar contains a lot of sugars which provide a quick fix of energy. It is quite similar to humans in which our bodies much prefer the breakdown of sugars rather than protein or fat breakdown. Blood may provide important nutrients but it lacks a lot of the sugars that nectar has, like fructose, glucose, and sucrose.